# Why I am unable to send mail using nodemailer?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bcrypt

The below is my function for nodemailer -

```
function mailer(firstName,emailId,password){
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        host: process.env.HOST, // hostname
        secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
        port: process.env.OUTLOOK_PORT, // port for secure SMTP
        tls: {
           ciphers:'SSLv3'
        },
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAILID,
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
      });
      
      var mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAILID,
        to: emailId,
        subject: 'DM automation tool login details',
        text: 'Hi ' + firstName + ','
         + '\n\nThank you for registering.\nYou can now login to the account using the password ' + password +
         '\nPlease click on the given link to login to your account http://localhost:8080/login' + 
         '\n\nNote : Please make sure to reset your password within an hour.'
      };
      
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
      });
    }
```

Here, i have given email id and password in .env file and I am using this function below.The customer will get a mail from my ID into his email id.

```
const createCustomer = async(req,res,next) => {
  try{ 
       
       var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*9000000) + 10000000;
       var db = req.con;
       const data = {
        "customerId" : id,
        "customerGroupId" : req.body.customerGroupId,
        "username" : req.body.username,
        "avatar" : req.file.filename,
        "email" : req.body.email,
        "password" : req.body.password,
        "mobileNumber" : req.body.mobileNumber,
    };
    console.log(data)

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(20);
    data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt);
    var pass = data.password;
    console.log(pass)
    
    if (!req.file.filename)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

    let filename = fs.readdirSync('./src/template-store/temporaryImage/')
    console.log(filename)
    var file = req.files

    let result = db.query(`INSERT INTO customers set ?`,[data],function(err,rows){
   
        if(err){
            res.json({
                success:0,
                message:"An error occurred",
                err
            })
        }
        else{
            res.json({
                success:1,
                message:"Inserted",
                data: data
            })
             mailer(req.body.username,req.body.email,req.body.password)
        }
    })
    
}

  catch(error){
       res.json({
           message:"An error occured",
           error:error
       })
  }
}
```

The password is correct.But I am getting this error-

Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor f17sm10086327pfk.184 - gsmtp
at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\coding backup\Brands\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:774:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (E:\coding backup\Brands\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1513:34)

Comment: Your error message says this...  did you follow up and read the suggested help file? **Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor  **

Comment: Yeah I guess there's 2 step verification added on my account.That's what creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to authenticate with `gmail` without a full `OAuth2` authentication.

I would suggest you to use an external service like SendGrid to send production transactional emails.

It even has a nice free plan, if your app is not huge, it won't be a problem! :)

PS: try to always avoid "sync" methods outside of the application bootstrap as it's blocking on the whole server (you are using `readdirSync` here).